# How to use date_add() to return last day of the year?

Tags: presto

I have a query where I want to limit the date range to 2019 only, would like to check if the following syntax is correct.

```
date(date_id) BETWEEN date_add('year', -1, date_trunc('year', current_date)) AND  date_add('day', -1, date_trunc('year', current_date))
```

Comment: Seems correct. You can also verify this with simple select: `SELECT date_add('year', -1, date_trunc('year', current_date));`.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen thanks! it is correct!

Answer (score 0):

> would like to check if the following syntax is correct.

Yes, your code is correct.